# Why does my RotateTransition throw errors after it runs for the first time?

Tags: multithreading, animation, javafx

Warning: This is my first time using threads and my first time trying out an animation. Please bear with me.

I want to rotate an ImageView. I set up a thread for it:

```
public class ThreadAnimation extends Thread
{
    private ImageView iv;
    private RotateTransition rt;

    public ThreadAnimation(ImageView iv)
    {
            this.iv = iv;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            RotateTransition r = new RotateTransition();
            r.setToAngle(360);
            r.setCycleCount(1);
            r.setDuration(Duration.millis(300));
            r.setNode(iv);
            r.play();

            try
            {
                sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I call this inside my controller class, upon pressing a Button.

```
animation.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle (ActionEvent abschicken)
    {
        ThreadAnimation thread = null;      //ANIMATION PIZZA
        if (thread == null)
        {
            thread = new ThreadAnimation(olivenview);
            thread.start();
        }
    }
});
```

My ImageView *olivenview* will rotate just like I wanted it to. However it takes quite a long time until it seems to stop (I can see it because the button triggering it still looks triggered for a while) and when I go ahead to press it a second time afterwards, I get a nonstop error stream with a lot of null pointer exceptions. I am very clueless, can anyone help me out? Is this due to my Thread Setup or does the problem lie somewhere else (in code that I didn't post here)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you do not need threads for this. Notice the `.play()` method returns immediately and the animation will run in the background.

That being said, try this.

```
...
//Create your rotation
final RotateTransition r = new RotateTransition();
r.setToAngle(360);
r.setCycleCount(1);
r.setDuration(Duration.millis(300));
r.setNode(iv);

//When the button is pressed play the rotation. Try experimenting with .playFromStart() instead of .play()
button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent action) {
        r.play();
    }
});

...
```

On an other note I recommend switching to java 8 so that you can use lambda expressions instead of the anonymous class!

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why it would behave the way it does currently though? I was expecting threads to be unecessary here, but wanted to try them out. Is that what causes the errors upon repeated Button presses?

Comment: Firstly, `thread` is always null (cause you set it to null just before) so no need to check with the if statement. Second your thread runs forever because of the `while(true)`. So each time you press the button, you start a new thread that constantly and forever starts new rotations. The error might be thrown from simply starting too many rotations for the computer to handle. If you explain why you want to use threads we might be able to help. Though I recommend just using the solution I proposed in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You helped me understand it, and I could easily fix it by removing the =null part! I suppose thats what the error came from initially.   I can understand why you would be confused about the use of threads here.

Comment: Great! Glad you figured it out! (btw if my solution answered your question, you can press the check mark to accept my answer and mark your question as solved)